# Most efficeint way to store nested dict in local file/database

Tags: python, database, nested

I have this data structure:

```
username = mor1
data ={
username:{
    '27.05.2021':{name:'mor', age:'22'},
    '27.05.2020':{name:'mori', age:'21'}
    }
}
```

I want to be able to work with sqlite local database file, and not pickle the whole data.

So I start using the sqlitedict package +defaultdict collection but it is limited to table name
(username) and key (date) so I will retrieve all user dict while all I want is to update the name and not the age.

Any better solutions ?

Comment: mongodb and tinydb are both document based databases that can store/query nested dict's.

Comment: tinydb lack of: ACID guarantees. and access from multiple processes or threads,

Comment: mongodb  is not file based - req installation of local server.